# Laptop Charger Short Damage

Tags: laptop, battery, power

today while I was plugging in my laptop charger a really unfortunate incident happened. The laptop side plug fell down and made contact with the wall jack as I was plugging it in causing a short. It sparked and tripped the fuse. Both ends of the charger melted a bit.

On the laptop side, a small portion of the outer metal layer melted and on the wall side a small amount of the upper right jack melted off. I've tested in a safe place and the green light on the charger is still coming on and it appears to be working correctly.

My question, is this damage superficial and therefore could still be used with my laptop? Or could it cause a damage to my laptop if I were to plug it in?

Comment: @fixer1234 What evidence do you have for the damage being localized?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Obviously, none of us have seen the equipment so the only "evidence" is the description of the event and the damage.  The current operation of the charger can be easily checked with a voltmeter.  I think the future possibilities you describe in your answer are remote.  As you point out, however, a replacement charger is not expensive.  Out of an abundance of caution and for peace of mind, it could be prudent to replace it.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the charger. New chargers aren't all that expensive; new laptops are quite expensive; new houses are very expensive. Why take the risk?

You don't know what damage has been caused to the charger. It could be OK apart from the cosmetic damage. It could be damaged in a way that causes it to break your laptop, either instantly by supplying completely the wrong power characteristics, or by providing slightly out-of-spec power characteristics over a period of time, so the laptop works but you're straining the components and it dies earlier than it should. The charger could be damaged in a way that turns it into a fire hazard, either by overheating straight away or by having reduced protection against power surges, high load or whatever.

Even if you feel the probability of breaking the laptop of burning your house down is low, the damage caused by either event is still high enough that using the damaged charger is at least moderately risky.